# How to read a big excel file in Java without error OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Tell me please, how to read a big excel file (31MB) in Java without error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded at Parser.main(Parser.java:17)

where line 17 its: Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)

Method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String excelFilePath = "file.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
            System.out.print(" - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    workbook.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

I tried like this:

1.Change *VM Options for importer*;

2.Settings -> Build -> Compiler and change *Shared build process heap size*;

3.Run -> Edit Configurations;

But nothing helped. How fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the heap size memory by using -Xmx option, in Intellij you can do like that (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html):

1. From the main menu, select Help | Change Memory Settings.
2. Set the necessary amount of memory that you want to allocate and click Save and Restart.